# How to convert folder to zip. file in asp classic

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

Can any one help me in how to convert folder to zip file in classic asp.

```
<% 
Dim objZip 
Response.write("new") 
Set objZip = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
Response.write("yahoo") 
objZip.Pack "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\NewZIp\Images\SMM.JPEG", "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\NewZIp\Images.zip" 
objZip.Pack "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\NewZIp\Images\IMS.JPEG", "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\NewZIp\Images.zip" 
Set objZip = Nothing 
%>
```

I am using this one code for convert folder to zip

Comment: What did you try? A quick Google search took me right to a working example: http://forums.aspfree.com/code-bank-54/creating-zip-files-using-classic-asp-66544.html

Comment: HI,                                                                        <%
Dim objZip
Response.write("new")
Set objZip = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Response.write("yahoo")
objZip.Pack "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\NewZIp\Images\SMM.JPEG", "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\NewZIp\Images.zip"
objZip.Pack "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\NewZIp\Images\IMS.JPEG", "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\NewZIp\Images.zip"
Set objZip = Nothing
%>                                                                      I am using this one code for convert folder to zip

Answer (score -2):

This can be easily done in asp.net using C#. Following code will help you out to zip a folder.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Packaging;

namespace ZipSample
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            AddFileToZip("Output.zip", @"C:\Windows\ABC.exe");
            AddFileToZip("Output.zip", @"C:\Windows\System32\DEF.exe");
        }

        private const long BUFFER_SIZE = 4096;

        private static void AddFileToZip(string zipFilename, string fileToAdd)
        {
            using (Package zip = System.IO.Packaging.Package.Open(zipFilename, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
            {
                string destFilename = ".\\" + Path.GetFileName(fileToAdd);
                Uri uri = PackUriHelper.CreatePartUri(new Uri(destFilename, UriKind.Relative));
                if (zip.PartExists(uri))
                {
                    zip.DeletePart(uri);
                }
                PackagePart part = zip.CreatePart(uri, "",CompressionOption.Normal);
                using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(fileToAdd, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                {
                    using (Stream dest = part.GetStream())
                    {
                        CopyStream(fileStream, dest);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private static void CopyStream(System.IO.FileStream inputStream, System.IO.Stream outputStream)
        {
            long bufferSize = inputStream.Length < BUFFER_SIZE ? inputStream.Length : BUFFER_SIZE;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
            int bytesRead = 0;
            long bytesWritten = 0;
            while ((bytesRead = inputStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
            {
                outputStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                bytesWritten += bufferSize;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The request was for Classic ASP and not .Net